# PHP get data from soap service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I need to get data from http://ws.jrtwebservices.com/jrtlowfaresearch/jrtlfs.asmx, this service need credential information.such as ID, userid and system value. I put these information into one string:

```
$xml_post_string = "<POS><Source> <RequestorID Type='21' ID='xxx'/> </Source> <TPA_Extensions> <Provider><System>xxx</System> <Userid>xxx</Userid>  </Provider></TPA_Extensions></POS>"
```

And i also defined SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('uri' => "http://ws.jrtwebservices.com",
                                 'location => "http://ws.jrtwebservices.com/jrtlowfaresearch/jrtlfs.asmx") );
```

I call soapCall as:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('do_LowfareSearch',array($xml_post_string),array('soapaction' => 'http://jrtechnologies.com/do_LowfareSearch'));
```

Does anybody know why i get empty response?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, the request looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xm...">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:do_LowfareSearch>
            <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">
                "<POS><Source> <RequestorID Type='21' ID='xxx'/> </Source> <TPA_Extensions> <Provider <System>xxx</System> <Userid>xxx</Userid>  </Provider></TPA_Extensions></POS>"
            </param0>
        </ns1:do_LowfareSearch>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The client used the method you passed but could not structure the parameters the way you gave them. All of your parameters are just in `" "` inside of `<param0>`.

(Also, you are missing a `'` after location. `'location => "http:...`)

When you make your SOAP client you want to set the WSDL, it will do all the XML formatting for you.

[The WSDL](http://ws.jrtwebservices.com/jrtlowfaresearch/jrtlfs.asmx?WSDL) should have the location in it so you do not need to worry about that.

[I like to use a WSDL validator to test out the methods and see their parameters.](http://validwsdl.com/)

You should structure the information you want to pass as [arrays or a classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) and let the SOAP client and WSDL convert it into the XML you need.

So something like this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
//SOAP Client
$wsdl = "http://ws.jrtwebservices.com/jrtlowfaresearch/jrtlfs.asmx?WSDL"; 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                        'trace' => true, //to debug
                                        )); 
try {
    $args = array(
        'companyname'=> 'xxx',
        'name'=> 'xxx',
        'system'=> 'xxx',
        'userid'=> 'xxx',
        'password'=> 'xxx',
        'conversationid'=>'xxx',
        'entry'=> 'xxx',
        );
    $result = $client->__soapCall('do_LowfareSearch', $args);
    return $result;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "Error: {$e}";
}
//to debug the xml sent to the service
echo($client->__getLastRequest());
//to view the xml sent back
echo($client->__getLastResponse());
?>
```